# HTML: quotation marks being automatically added at image source

Tags: html, image, google-chrome-extension

I'm inside a content script in a Chrome Extension. I want to add the following code to dinamically create a **div** element, that contains some text and a **image** with a **src** attribute and an **ID**:

```
     var errorMessage = document.createElement('div');

     errorMessage.id = "errorMessage";

     errorMessage.innerHTML = "error type <img src=chrome.extension.getURL(\"icone_redX.png\") id=\"redX\">";
```

However, the browser is messing with my code, generating this result:

```
<div id="errorMessage">error type <img src="chrome.extension.getURL("icone_redX.png")" id="redX"></div>
```

So, instead of looking for the `icone_redX.png` archive at the extension directory, it looks for the `chrome.extension.getURL("icone_redX.png")` archive at the current page's directory. How to prevent him for adding this quotation marks?

Comment: prepend the src with javascript:chrome.extension.getUrl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait, basically you did want to set the src to the result of `chrome.extension.getURL()`, no?

Hence it should be this:

```
errorMessage.innerHTML = "error type <img src="+chrome.extension.getURL("icone_redX.png")+" id=\"redX\">";
```

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful!